# C# .Net core Pdf ocr using TesseractEngine but not get accuracy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am get all text from pdf using TesseractEngine but I can't best accuracy.

I am trying first convert pdf to image using MagickImageCollection then this image pass into TesseractEngine
but can't get proper all taxes.

I need each and every word of pdf. I need to find pdf to VendorName,InvoiceDate,DueDate,TotalAmount etc.
and store into database table.

Comment: I suggest you could consider using some existing service like [Azure computer-vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/) .